# Github API languages endpoint

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am getting some data from Github API and I encountered that to get languages for a particular repository I get following object. I want to know that what do these value numbers mean?

```
{
  "JavaScript": 1300078,
  "CSS": 71202,
  "Shell": 2513
}
```

Comment: How did you get to this data @Om3ga? I am trying to find a way to get to it too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are [bytes of code](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-languages) per language in this repo.

Comment: great. is it possible to find percentage for each value?

Comment: @2619 AFAIK, not directly form the API, but you could just sum all the values and divide each value by the total sum.

Comment: Sorry for that but I meant only for JavaScript I want to find percentage. Then instead of showing that value I want to show percentage. That approach doesnt seem to be given desired percentages.

Comment: @2619 why not? 1300078/(1300078+71202+2513)=0.9463. Multiply by 100 to express it as a percent 94.63%.

Comment: how can i find all github languages

Comment: For a specific repository? Those would be the keys of the returned object